# How to use bash control a keyboard

Tags: command-line, keyboard, x11

How to use bash command control a Keyboard.

e.g.
what is a command in bash for pressing ctrl+c, ctrl+l, etc..?

Comment: There's no bash command for that, bash doesn't have anything to do with keyboards. There are external applications you can invoke from the command line. Are you running in a GUI? How do you plan to determine which window you'll send the key events to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AutoKey` is a desktop automation utility for Linux and X11. It allows the
  automation of virtually any task by responding to typed abbreviations and
  hotkeys. It offers a full-featured GUI that makes it highly accessible for
  novices, as well as Python scripting .... Here is the link to [Autokey's homepage](http://code.google.com/p/autokey).

Note: When I first looked at *Autokey*, its scripting interface could not handle Unicode fully. I forget exactly how that was, but it was something like it could process UTF-8 internally, but couldn't deliver it to the something-or-other. If it wasn't for that, I'd be using it today; it looks great, and it has a good reputation (I know it from Windows-land). Otherwise, it is quite comprehensive. I believe it is a fork of *Autoit3* (again Windows).. I've used Autoit3 and it is absolutely fully featured. I think Autokey is similar....  `Autokey` is available in the Ubuntu repository..

---

`xdotool` lets you programatically (or manually) simulate keyboard
  input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc.

```
xdotool key  --clearmodifiers --delay 40 "ctrl+shift+u"
```

---

Another option is package `xmacro`. It contains *macroplay* and *xmacrorec* (and xmacrorec2).  `xmacrorec` can be used to record mouse and keyboard events on any X11 display.  xmacroplay can be used to playback recorded events or send any other mouse/keyboard events you choose.

```
  echo -n "KeyStrPress Control_L 
           KeyStrPress Alt_L   
           KeyStrPress a    
           KeyStrRelease a    
           KeyStrRelease Alt_L   
           KeyStrRelease Control_L"|
           xmacroplay :0.0 &>/dev/null
```

---